# What to do for 'Non-Nullable Property Must Contain A Non-Null Value' for property bound at run time

Tags: c#, non-nullable

What is standard practice with new `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` setting for classes with properties that are bound at runtime that you know the value will not be null?  Examples:

**Strongly typed appsettings.json classes**

```
public class CustomSettings
{
    public CustomObject CustomObject { get; set; }
}
public class CustomObject
{
    public string NonNullProperty { get; set; }
}
```

With json of:

```
{
    "CustomSettings": {
        "CustomObject": {
            "NonNullProperty": "Some Value Here"
        }
    }
}
```

**Custom MSBuild Task Properties**

```
public class DependencyCopy : Task
{
    [Required]
    public string StartFolder { get; set; } = default!;
    [Required]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; } = default!;
    [Required]
    public string Configuration { get; set; } = default!;
    [Required]
    public string OutputFolder { get; set; }
}
```

With *.csproj settings of:

```
<DependencyCopy StartFolder="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" ProjectName="$(ProjectName)" Configuration="$(Configuration)" OutputFolder="$(OutputPath)" />
```

Should I be using `#nullable disable` and `#nullable restore`?  Settings properties to `= default!`?

Comment: See also (possible duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60812587/c-sharp-non-nullable-field-lateinit I'd use `default!` or `null!`here.